# how to compile multiple different jar files in sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, compilation, sbt

I have a project in sbt and want to compile multiple jar which all contains a different main class and can be submitted to spark.
and beacause this kind of jar is very a lot and most of them have some common dependencies ,it is not convenient to split them into different subprojects. ALL of these main class source files are in same directory, say , under  src/main/scala/com.xx.yy. So how to write the build.sbt to compile all the main class into different jars or compile by the name of the main class,just like compile different subprojects.
Please help, sbt is very hard to use and i cant find any documentation on this .thanks very much.

Comment: no , and sbt assembly isn't what i want. i just want different jars,and schedule the jar in different way to spark. you can think it just like the official spark/examples directory,there are many examples all in one directory ,and produce independent jar file in another target directory.but now spark is built by maven,i am searching a solution in sbt

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you have many main classes in your src folder. And you want to be able to run them from spark-submit from one jar. Then the answer is:

1. You do not need to create different jars for each of the main classes.
2. Just donot define any "mainClass" in your build.sbt file, and build a normal jar with all these classes. (The output will be one jar which has all your classes, the multiple main classes, and also other classess and libraries that are re-used)
3. While doing a spark-submit with this jar, you can specify which main-class you want your spark job to run using the "--class" tag, and run the specific mainclass/application you need.

Comment: it sounds like a nice idea,i will try it!  But on the other hand ,the official spark examples directory indeed have many different main class in one src,and produced many independent jars ! Any idea how or can it works in sbt?

Comment: Please share the link as to which spark examples you are referring to. Also, doing via Maven or Gradle is a more elegant way of building projects instead of sbt.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples